# How can two cells with different var work?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sorry for maybe stupid question ,but i'm  a begginer in this and I'm trying to figure it out by myself :D
**So this is my function:**

```
function CheckSales() {
// Fetch the monthly sales
var monthSalesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("non inventory").getRange("C28");
var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValue();
// Check totals sales
if (monthSales < 200 ){
// Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("data").getRange("L5");
var emailAddress = "d.lewandowski@autodoc.pl";
// Send Alert Email.
var message = "Przygotuj zapotrzebowanie! Inwentarz spadł do wartości " + monthSales; // Second column
var subject = "Low Inventory Alert";
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
}
```

and everything is as i want it, but what should i do if i want the same function, but different var, for example:

That's the part that i already have, but what should i do if i want to add for cell C29 if monthSales <250. And then both of them working at the same time?

```
var monthSalesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("non inventory").getRange("C28");
var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValue();
// Check totals sales
if (monthSales < 200 )
```

Comment: Welcome to [so].  Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please review the wording of your question and explain what you mean by "i want the same function, but different var,". P.S. You might also will find helpful to read [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what Damian wants is a function where you can change the range reference and value to check against. I would do:

```
function checkSales(rangeRef,compareTo) {
  // Fetch the monthly sales
  var monthSalesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("non inventory").getRange(rangeRef);
  var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValue();
  // Check totals sales
  if (monthSales < compareTo ){
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("data").getRange("L5");
    var emailAddress = "d.lewandowski@autodoc.pl";
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = "Przygotuj zapotrzebowanie! Inwentarz spadł do wartości " + monthSales; // Second column
    var subject = "Low Inventory Alert";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

And then you can call the function twice with different arguments from the function that you actually run:

```
function checkAllSales(){
  checkSales("C28",200);
  checkSales("C29",250);
}
```

Comment: awesome, thank you, that's exactly what i meant